# update several columns of a table at once

Tags: postgresql

In postgresql, I want to update several rows of a table according to their id. This doesn't work:

```
    UPDATE table SET othertable_id = 5 WHERE id = 2, 45, 22, 75
```

What is the correct syntax for this?

Comment: The title of your question says "several columns", the body says "several rows". Which is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an [IN operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-comparisons.html#FUNCTIONS-COMPARISONS-IN-SCALAR):

```
update the_table
  set othertable_id = 5
where id in (2,45,22,75);
```